# Memory Map error on my simple sudoku program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

So for a project i decided to make a sudoku solver that first uses finds naked singles (cells with only one possible value) and then just brute forces its way to victory.

This is my first time using multiple files in program and as such my first time using a makefile, but the errors i am getting aren't during compile time so i think my makefile is fine.

I tried debugging with GSB but it doesn't really seem to help all that much... If i had to guess i think te problem is occuring with my class Cell's destructor.

To give you a brief overview of the project so I dont just spit code at you:
The class puzzle contains a 9x9 matrix of the class Cell. The class Cell contains two integers to represent position on the board (row and column), an integer value (the actual value of the cell) and an array of 9 booleans that represent the possible candidates for the the value of the cell (0 in the array represents the value is not a possible candidate, 1 means it is) - so for example candidate[2] is the third value in the array, so if it was 1 it means that 3 is a possible value for the cell.

Now onto the code. My code is made up of 5 files: main.cpp, puzzle.cpp, cell.cpp, puzzle.h, and cell.h. [Here is a link to my pastebin of the 5 files and the makefile](http://pastebin.com/u/permatrash).

I would advise you not pay attention to the huge functions in puzzle.cpp (checkConflicts() and eliminateCandidates()) as they are both just long if statements that make sure no cells conflict/elinimate confliction candidates.

The debugger jumps to the cell destructor that deletes the candidate array, but i don't see a problem with it!

Here is a copy of the error that i get after making and running the program:

```
$ make
g++ -c puzzle.cpp cell.h
g++ -c cell.cpp
g++ -o sudsolve main.cpp puzzle.o cell.o

$ ./sudsolve 
*** Error in `./sudsolve': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000a30fd4 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7f576)[0x7fcaecc1f576]
./sudsolve[0x40bbdb]
./sudsolve[0x401cd2]
./sudsolve[0x402a12]
./sudsolve[0x402a84]
./sudsolve[0x402299]
./sudsolve[0x401e38]
./sudsolve[0x40156a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fcaecbc1ea5]
./sudsolve[0x400eb9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 2097787                            /home/silman/Documents/programming/ecs60/sudsolve/sudsolve
0060d000-0060e000 r--p 0000d000 fc:04 2097787                            /home/silman/Documents/programming/ecs60/sudsolve/sudsolve
0060e000-0060f000 rw-p 0000e000 fc:04 2097787                            /home/silman/Documents/programming/ecs60/sudsolve/sudsolve
00a30000-00a51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcaec89b000-7fcaec99e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 1576781                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fcaec99e000-7fcaecb9e000 ---p 00103000 fc:04 1576781                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fcaecb9e000-7fcaecb9f000 r--p 00103000 fc:04 1576781                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fcaecb9f000-7fcaecba0000 rw-p 00104000 fc:04 1576781                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fcaecba0000-7fcaecd5e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 1576733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fcaecd5e000-7fcaecf5d000 ---p 001be000 fc:04 1576733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fcaecf5d000-7fcaecf61000 r--p 001bd000 fc:04 1576733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fcaecf61000-7fcaecf63000 rw-p 001c1000 fc:04 1576733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fcaecf63000-7fcaecf68000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcaecf68000-7fcaecf7c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 1576758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaecf7c000-7fcaed17c000 ---p 00014000 fc:04 1576758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaed17c000-7fcaed17d000 r--p 00014000 fc:04 1576758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaed17d000-7fcaed17e000 rw-p 00015000 fc:04 1576758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaed17e000-7fcaed263000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 271362                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fcaed263000-7fcaed462000 ---p 000e5000 fc:04 271362                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fcaed462000-7fcaed46a000 r--p 000e4000 fc:04 271362                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fcaed46a000-7fcaed46c000 rw-p 000ec000 fc:04 271362                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fcaed46c000-7fcaed481000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcaed481000-7fcaed4a4000 r-xp 00000000 fc:04 1576709                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fcaed684000-7fcaed689000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcaed6a0000-7fcaed6a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcaed6a3000-7fcaed6a4000 r--p 00022000 fc:04 1576709                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fcaed6a4000-7fcaed6a6000 rw-p 00023000 fc:04 1576709                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fff88ba8000-7fff88bc9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff88bfe000-7fff88c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It would help if you would have attached all files and symbolicated the crash log.

Comment: Did you forget to upload something? There are only three files including the makefile.

Comment: Sorry i had to make them public, you should be able to see them

Comment: @JustSid: I dont know what you mean by attached all the files? Is the pastebin not the right way to share large amounts of code? Also what is a symbolicated crash log?

Sorry i am new to this stuff

Comment: dereferencing null pointer?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `delete` on a variable that wasn't allocated using `new`. For reference, here is the stripped `Cell` class from the pastebin:

```
class Cell{
public:
    ~Cell()
    {
        delete[] candidates;
    }

private:
        bool candidates[9];
};
```

The space for the candidates array is allocated together with your class, and it will automatically freed when your class is deleted (which happens automatically since its allocated on the stack). You only need to call delete for memory that was previously allocated using `new`.

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't know C++ did that kind of garbage collection for its classes. Thank you!

Comment: I have deleted the destructor in the cell class, but now I am getting an error upon compiling stating " In function Puzzle:~Puzzle (the destructor for puzzle) undefined reference to Cel::~Cell." But i never explicitly call the destructor.

Comment: @user0123 You also need to delete the definition from your header file. As a side note, this isn't some kind of garbage collection, the member variables of your classes memory layout, and are automatically allocated as part of your instance.